# How do I extract an HTML element based on its class?

Tags: html, perl, html-parsing

I'm just starting out in Perl, and wrote a simple script to do some web scraping. I'm using WWW::Mechanize and HTML::TreeBuilder to do most of the work, but I've run into some trouble. I have the following HTML:

```html
<table class="winsTable">
    <thead>...</thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class = "wins">15</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I know there are some modules that get data from tables, but this is a special case; not all the data I want is in a table. So, I tried:

```
my $tree = HTML::TreeBuilder->new_from_url( $url );
my @data = $tree->find('td class = "wins"');
```

But `@data` returned empty. I know this method would work without the class name, because I've successfully parsed data with `$tree->find('strong')`. So, is there a module that can handle this type of HTML syntax? I scanned through the HTML::TreeBuilder documentation and didn't find anything that appeared to, but I could be wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm using excellent (but a bit slow sometimes) `HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath` module:

```
my $tree = HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath->new_from_content( $mech->content() );
my @data = $tree->findvalues('//table[ @class = "winsTable" ]//td[@class = "wins"]');
```

Answer (score 10):

You could use the `look_down` method to find the specific tag and attributes you're looking for.  This is in the `HTML::Element` module (which is imported by `HTML::TreeBuilder`).

```
my $data = $tree->look_down(
    _tag  => 'td',
    class => 'wins'
);

print $data->content_list, "\n" if $data; #prints '15' using the given HTML

$data = $tree->look_down(
    _tag  => 'td',
    class => 'losses'
);

print $data->content_list, "\n" if $data; #prints nothing using the given HTML
```

Comment: I am using the same scenario but iam getting the following error:
odd number of elements in hash assignment at /usr/local/share/perl5/HTML/TreeBuilder.pm line 207

Answer (score 1):

(This is kind of a supplementary answer to [dspain's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17636459/1743811))

Actually you missed a spot in the [HTML::TreeBuilder documentation](http://search.cpan.org/~cjm/HTML-Tree-5.03/lib/HTML/TreeBuilder.pm#METHODS) where it says,

> Objects of this class inherit the methods of both HTML::Parser and HTML::Element. The methods inherited from HTML::Parser are used for building the HTML tree, and the methods inherited from HTML::Element are what you use to scrutinize the tree. **Besides this (HTML::TreeBuilder) documentation, you must also carefully read the HTML::Element documentation**, and also skim the HTML::Parser documentation -- probably only its parse and parse_file methods are of interest.

(Note that the bold formatting is mine, it's not in the documentation)

This indicates that you should read [HTML::Element's documentation](http://search.cpan.org/~cjm/HTML-Tree-5.03/lib/HTML/Element.pm) as well, where you would find the [`find` method](http://search.cpan.org/~cjm/HTML-Tree-5.03/lib/HTML/Element.pm#find) which says

> This is just an alias to find_by_tag_name

This should tell you that it doesn't work for class names, but its description also mentions a [`look_down` method](http://search.cpan.org/~cjm/HTML-Tree-5.03/lib/HTML/Element.pm#look_down) which can be found slightly further down. If you look at the example, you'd see that it does what you want. And [dspain's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17636459/1743811) shows precisely how in your case.

To be fair, the documentation is not that easy to navigate.

Answer (score 0):

I found the [this](http://htmlparsing.com/perl.html) link the most useful at telling me how to extract specific information from html content. I used the last example on the page:

```
use v5.10;
use WWW::Mechanize;
use WWW::Mechanize::TreeBuilder;

my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new;
WWW::Mechanize::TreeBuilder->meta->apply($mech);

$mech->get( 'http://htmlparsing.com/' );

# Find all <h1> tags
my @list = $mech->find('h1');

# or this way <----- I found this way very useful to pinpoint exact classes with in some html
my @list = $mech->look_down('_tag' => 'h1', 
                            'class' => 'main_title');

# Now just iterate and process
foreach (@list) {
    say $_->as_text();
}
```

This seemed so much simpler to get up and running than any of the other modules that I looked at. Hope this helps!